# SCM Music Player to play an individual song

Tags: javascript

Evening,

My request is how to make the 'SCM Music Player' play an individual (different) song, when entering another page.

For example, 
On Pg.1 (index.php) I want to play the song 'The Script - Hall of Fame ft. will.i.am' from YouTube

On Pg.2 (second.php) I want to play the song 'The Script - If You Could See Me Now' from YouTube

But, when I place a hyperlink from index.php, to second.php, it will successfully redirect, however the SCM Music Player will **STILL** play the song from index.php, which I obviously don't want, I want it to play the song from second.php

If anyone could help me how to fix this, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after playing around with the script.js, I fixed it.

I'm 100% confident this probably isn't the correct way of doing it, however, it works!

Here's how, find the below from '**script.js**'

```
                    }else if(filter(tar.href).indexOf(filter(location.host))==-1 ){
                    if(tar.href.match(/^http(s)?/)){
                        //external links
                        window.open(tar.href,'_blank');
                        window.focus();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
```

Replace with

```
                    }else if(filter(tar.href).indexOf(filter(location.host))==0 ){
                    if(tar.href.match(/^http(s)?/)){
                        //external links
                        window.open(tar.href,'_top');
                        window.focus();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
```

It seemed to work!

Enjoy.